# How do I list UIElements in ListView items?

Tags: wpf, listview, uielement, itemcollection

I'm trying to access `UIElement`s in the `VisualTree` of a `ListView` but the `ItemsCollection` is empty even though the `ListView` `IsLoaded`, `IsInitialized` and has items in `DataContext`.

How can I access `UIElements` in a `ListView`? Is there an event I can attach myself on to wait for the items to be accessible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to `ItemsContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` and in the handler check whether the status is `ContainersGenerated`:

```
myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += OnListViewItemsStatusChanged;
```

-

```
private void OnListViewItemsStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated) {
        // access items
    }
}
```